# I need help finding a web element in selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Can some one help me to locate an element to input the password to the form as HTML follow:

```
<label><b>PASSWORD</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your PASSWORD" name="pw" required>
```

I tried:
element = driver.find_element_by_name("pw")

but it's not working. This error is what I got:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="pw"]
```

Any ideas how to solve this?
Thank

Comment: Try elements = driver.find_elements_by_name("pw")  ? Because find_element_by_name is used in case you are sure that there is a single existence of name in the DOM.

Comment: @VidyaSagar if it's unable to locate a single element, why would trying to locate multiple elements work?

Comment: The element you are looking for is probably inside an IFRAME.

Comment: Do you come to this page from another page? Check if that element is loaded before you try to find it.